# Backbone - setting el in render functions?

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

I am working on a web page using BackboneJS. The HTML page contains 2 divs which are acting as columns and each item will be either on the first column, either on the second. I am not sure how to set the `el` element on the collection view. Currently I am setting it dinamically in the collection `render` function, but for some reason there are more items (divs) created in the right column. Here is the code. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better approach?

HTML snippet:

```
<div class="columns" id="col1"></div>
<div class="columns" id="col2"></div>
```

The Backbone view should distribute the items on both `col1` and `col2` divs, so I cannot set `el` in the collection view as usual, I have to set it somehow dynamically.

Here is the MenusView collection corresponding view:

```
var application = application || {};

application.MenusView = Backbone.View.extend({
//el: '#col1',

initialize: function(initialmenus) {
    console.log("Initializaing MenusView");
    this.collection = new application.Menus(initialmenus);
    this.render();
},

render: function() {
    var count = true;
    this.collection.each(function(item) {
        //setting el dynamically at rendering, so we can distribute divs to col1 and col2
        this.setElement($('#col' + (count ? '1' : '2')));
        count = !count;
        this.renderMenu(item);
    }, this);
},

renderMenu: function(item) {
    var menuView = new application.MenuView({
        model: item
    });
    this.$el.append(menuView.render().el);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? Don't modify the parent dynamically at rendering, instead, alternatively pick which child-DIV to render to.

```
<div class="columnWrapper">
    <div class="columns"></div>
    <div class="columns"></div>
</div>

var application = application || {};

application.MenusView = Backbone.View.extend({
// Your collection view's "el" is now the wrapper div
el: "div.columnWrapper",

initialize: function(initialmenus) {
    console.log("Initializaing MenusView");
    this.collection = new application.Menus(initialmenus);
    this.render();
},

render: function() {
    var count = true;
    this.collection.each(function(item) { 
        this.renderMenu(item, count);

        count = !count;
    }, this);
},

renderMenu: function(item, count) {
    var menuView = new application.MenuView({
        model: item
    });
    var childIndex = count ? 1 : 2;
    this.$(".columns:nth-child(" + childIndex + ")").append(menuView.render().el);
}
});
```

Comment: Something wrong with the selector in renderMenu function :( Other than that, I think it's a great ideea, I gotta see if it works

Comment: Well, WHAT is wrong? Error messages? Logs? Can't help you if you don't participate... PS: There's a missing quote mark. Fixed answer.

Comment: Yes Bernardo, the missing quote, sorry for not mentioning it. Great stuff, working fine. Thanks!